# Retrieve a previous version of a file in Apanta

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, aptana

I have accidentally saved a file then closed its window in Apatan not realizing that I was editing the wrong file. Please help, is there a way to retrieve a previous version of a file?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution here: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Comparing+Different+Versions+of+a+File